# Class extend CSS

Tags: css

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5BhaS/2/) I have some elements with different rules in different contexts, but some of rules are the same.

Is it okay to define one class for them and to extend it in different context?

```
.read-more {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#one .read-more {
    background: yellow;
}
#two .read-more {
    background: #ff9e13;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "is it OK"?

Comment: is it correct? or if it's a class all rules in it must be same in all contexts?

Comment: It's 100% valid CSS. What was your specific concern?

Comment: ok, thank you) I've asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893668/same-class-names-for-different-sections, and after Im a little confused with classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend a class to fit different needs.

Note that the attributes which are not overridden will be taken from the original class.

Example:

```
.read-more {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url('img.png');
}
#one .read-more {
    background: yellow;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

All elements with just `read-more` will have a red border, but those with id `one` and class `read-more` will have green border.

Also note, the attribute `background` will remove the attribute `background-image` in the base class. So, element with id `one` and class `read-more` won't have the image.